# Sending Email from Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm confused with my customized script for Google Apps (particularly for Google Spreadsheets).

I reproduced the lesson from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails#section-2-improvements (see "Section 2: Improvements") but it doesn't work: script resends all the emails once again even if the cell already contains "EMAIL_SENT" (I use "NOTIFICATION_SENT" instead of this).

Here is the source of customized script:

```
var NOTIFICATION_SENT = "NOTIFICATION_SENT";

function NotifyNewBooking() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 47;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:N48
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 17)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "natalya@berdyanskaya56.ru";
    var subject = "Строка № " + row + ": " + "новое бронирование";
    var message = "Уведомление о новом бронировании!" + "\n" + "\nДанные нового бронирования:" + "\n" + "\nЗаезд: " + row[0] + "\nВыезд: " + row[1] + "\nНомер: " + "«" + row[2] + "»" + "\nТип размещения: " + row[3] + "\nЦена за ночь: " + row[4] + " руб." + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + row[8] + " руб." + "\n" + "\nИмя и фамилия гостя: " + row[5] + "\nМобильный телефон: " + row[6] + "\nЭлектронная почта: " + row[7] + "\n" + "\nПримечание: " + row[11] + "\n" + "\n* Просмотреть список всех бронирований можно тут: " + "www.bitly.com/b56guests";  
    var notificationSent = row[17];     // The column where notification status is put
    if (notificationSent != NOTIFICATION_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {name: "Мини-гостиница Бердянская 56", replyTo: "ruslan@berdyanskaya56.ru"});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 17).setValue(NOTIFICATION_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

The goal here is to send emails only if the cells in the column `row[17]` doesn't contain `NOTIFICATION_SENT`. Please, provide me with strong advice how to fix it.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Updated the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line : `var notificationSent = row[17];`

Try debugging the code by logging the values `Logger.log(row[17])` and `Logger.log(row[16])` and you will get `undefined` in row[17] and `NOTIFICATION_SENT` in row[16].

**Why?** Because Range.[getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2 dimensional array and array indexes start from 0.

It is also specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).

> Remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array will be indexed from [0][0].

So while row is fine because you have initialized *i to 0* in your for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { 
    var row = data[i]; 
    ....
```

you should subtract 1 from index when getting a column.

```
var notificationSent = row[17 - 1];
```

because if you have 17 columns, first value in array will start from index 0 up to 16.